# What is the difference between DLL made in Visual Studio and MinGW?

Tags: c++

I am doing a DLL from C++ source, using MVSC and DevCpp.

For MVSC, it produce .dll and .lib and for devcpp (using MinGW) only .dll and .def . (The same code as use to both procedure).

What is difference between ? What is the correct way to generate DLL to Windows ?

Comment: Besides being incompatible with each other?

Comment: [This may help answer your question](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Interoperability_of_Libraries_Created_by_Different_Compiler_Brands)

Comment: *What is the correct way to generate DLL to Windows* -- Your question needs to be more focused.  If you export `C` interfaces, use generic (Windows) types such as LONG, BOOL, etc., the DLL will work with practically any language that can call DLL functions.